# Using a variables to access elements in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is hard to explain.

I have a form builder (Question model) that creates form fields that belong to a specific event, these questions appear on the registration page handled by the Registration model.

There are default form fields that always stays the same and then X additional ones created by the form builder. The Question model has the field "db_field", which gets populated with the corresponding db field in the Registration model.

Note that the questions also have position_ids.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get answers display under the corresponding headings in a table in the index page, my view looks like this

```
<% @questions = Question.where(:event_id => @event.id).order(:position) %>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <% @questions.each do |q| %>
      <th><%= q.question %></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <% @event.registrations.each do |r| %>
    <tr>
      <% @questions.each do |q| %>
        <td><%= r.(q.db_field) %></td>
      <% end %>
    </td>
</table>
```

So basically I need 'q.db_field', which might be 'title', for instance, to call r.title - if that makes sense.

I've tried a few things, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance,
Charl

Comment: that did the trick! thank you very much. struggled for ages to get the answer on google.

Comment: Consider putting that comment in an answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object#send` to invoke methods on a given object.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html for more info.

so replacing `<%= r.(q.db_field) %>` with `<%= r.send(q.db_field) %>`  will allow you to use the field name from the DB.  If you need to specify arguments for the method being called, you can pass them in after the method name.   Per the docs,  method name can either be a symbol or a string, if it is a string, it will be converted to a symbol for you.